# 『このサイトにアクセスできません』と表示される

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aws, nginx, unicorn

お世話になっております。
下記の問題で知見がある方がいらっしゃいまいたらご教示お願いします。

## 起きている問題

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
`nginx+unicorn+rails`でサーバの構築をし、`AWS`上の`EC2`に`ALB`を経由してアクセスを試みているのですが、上記のように『このサイトにアクセスできません』と表示されてしまいます。

## 確認したこと

・Nginxが起動していることを確認

```
$ ps aux | grep nginx
root      4855  0.0  0.2 125708  2192 ?        Ss   20:48   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
nginx     4857  0.0  0.4 126140  4976 ?        S    20:48   0:00 nginx: worker process
ryouya    4968  0.0  0.0 119436   944 pts/0    S+   21:10   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

・Unicornが起動していることを確認

```
$ cat unicorn.log
：
：
I, [2020-05-18T20:21:22.358485 #4510]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 4518 exit 0> worker=0
I, [2020-05-18T20:21:22.358671 #4510]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 4520 exit 0> worker=1
I, [2020-05-18T20:21:22.358736 #4510]  INFO -- : master complete
I, [2020-05-18T20:21:24.819228 #4697]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
I, [2020-05-18T20:21:26.788253 #4697]  INFO -- : unlinking existing socket=/var/www/rails/coffee_app/tmp/sockets/.unicorn.sock
I, [2020-05-18T20:21:26.788432 #4697]  INFO -- : listening on addr=/var/www/rails/coffee_app/tmp/sockets/.unicorn.sock fd=11
I, [2020-05-18T20:21:26.843668 #4697]  INFO -- : master process ready
I, [2020-05-18T20:21:26.850775 #4707]  INFO -- : worker=1 ready
I, [2020-05-18T20:21:26.851214 #4705]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready

$ ps -ef | grep unicorn | grep -v grep
ryouya    4697     1  0 20:21 ?        00:00:01 unicorn_rails master -c /var/www/rails/coffee_app/config/unicorn.conf.rb -D -E production
ryouya    4705  4697  0 20:21 ?        00:00:00 unicorn_rails worker[0] -c /var/www/rails/coffee_app/config/unicorn.conf.rb -D -E production
ryouya    4707  4697  0 20:21 ?        00:00:00 unicorn_rails worker[1] -c /var/www/rails/coffee_app/config/unicorn.conf.rb -D -E production
```

・セキュリティグループの設定
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
セキュリティグループ設定のインバウンドは８０番ポートを許可していることを確認しました。

・ssl設定をfalseに設定していることを確認（まだssl証明書を発行してないため）
config/environments/production.rb

```
:
config.force_ssl = false
:
```

・ローカル上、EC2上で『curl [http://IPアドレス/](http://IP%E3%82%A2%E3%83%89%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B9/)』を打った時に下記が返ってくる

```
$ curl http://IPアドレス/
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test Page for the Nginx HTTP Server on Amazon Linux</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <style type="text/css">
            /*<![CDATA[*/
            body {
                background-color: #fff;
                color: #000;
                font-size: 0.9em;
                font-family: sans-serif,helvetica;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            :link {
                color: #c00;
            }
            :visited {
                color: #c00;
            }
            a:hover {
                color: #f50;
            }
            h1 {
                text-align: center;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0.6em 2em 0.4em;
                background-color: #294172;
                color: #fff;
                font-weight: normal;
                font-size: 1.75em;
                border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
            }
            h1 strong {
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 1.5em;
            }
            h2 {
                text-align: center;
                background-color: #3C6EB4;
                font-size: 1.1em;
                font-weight: bold;
                color: #fff;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0.5em;
                border-bottom: 2px solid #294172;
            }
            hr {
                display: none;
            }
            .content {
                padding: 1em 5em;
            }
            .alert {
                border: 2px solid #000;
            }

            img {
                border: 2px solid #fff;
                padding: 2px;
                margin: 2px;
            }
            a:hover img {
                border: 2px solid #294172;
            }
            .logos {
                margin: 1em;
                text-align: center;
            }
            /*]]>*/
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Welcome to <strong>nginx</strong> on Amazon Linux!</h1>

        <div class="content">
            <p>This page is used to test the proper operation of the
            <strong>nginx</strong> HTTP server after it has been
            installed. If you can read this page, it means that the
            web server installed at this site is working
            properly.</p>

            <div class="alert">
                <h2>Website Administrator</h2>
                <div class="content">
                    <p>This is the default <tt>index.html</tt> page that
                    is distributed with <strong>nginx</strong> on
                     Amazon Linux.  It is located in
                    <tt>/usr/share/nginx/html</tt>.</p>

                    <p>You should now put your content in a location of
                    your choice and edit the <tt>root</tt> configuration
                    directive in the <strong>nginx</strong>
                    configuration file
                    <tt>/etc/nginx/nginx.conf</tt>.</p>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="logos">
                <a href="http://nginx.net/"><img
                    src="nginx-logo.png" 
                    alt="[ Powered by nginx ]"
                    width="121" height="32" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

※ローカル上、EC2上でも結果は変わりませんでした。

・nginx.access.logでは正常に応答していることを確認

```
$ tail nginx.access.log
10.0.0.229 - - [18/May/2020:20:21:02 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3520 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
10.0.1.250 - - [18/May/2020:20:21:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3520 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
10.0.0.229 - - [18/May/2020:20:21:12 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3520 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
```

・nginx.error.log、unicorn.log
上記ファイルについてはWebにアクセスした際にエラーは出力されていませんでした。

・ブラウザの履歴を削除
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
ブラウザの履歴を削除したのですが、解決しませんでした。

## 関連ファイル

・coffee_app.conf(Nginxの設定ファイル)

```
error_log  /var/www/rails/coffee_app/log/nginx.error.log;
access_log /var/www/rails/coffee_app/log/nginx.access.log;

upstream unicorn_server {
    server unix:/var/www/rails/coffee_app/tmp/sockets/.unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name 54.250.29.214;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # Location of our static files
    root /var/www/rails/coffee_app/public;

    location ~ ^/assets/ {
        root /var/www/rails/coffee_app/public;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://unicorn_server;
            break;
        }
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
        root /var/www/rails/coffee_app/public;
    }
}
```

・unicorn.conf.rb

```
  $worker  = 2
  $timeout = 30
  $app_dir = "/var/www/rails/coffee_app"
  $listen  = File.expand_path 'tmp/sockets/.unicorn.sock', $app_dir
  $pid     = File.expand_path 'tmp/pids/unicorn.pid', $app_dir
  $std_log = File.expand_path 'log/unicorn.log', $app_dir
  # set config
  worker_processes  $worker
  working_directory $app_dir
  stderr_path $std_log
  stdout_path $std_log
  timeout $timeout
  listen  $listen
  pid $pid
  # loading booster
  preload_app true
  # before starting processes
  before_fork do |server, worker|
    defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
    old_pid = "#{server.config[:pid]}.oldbin"
    if old_pid != server.pid
      begin
        Process.kill "QUIT", File.read(old_pid).to_i
      rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
      end
    end
  end
  after_fork do |server, worker|
    defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end
```

## 環境

Rails 5.1.6
Ruby 2.5.1
Unicorn 5.4.1
Nginx 1.12.2

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/262821

Comment: 「curl コマンドの実行」と「ブラウザでのアクセス」は同じ端末でしょうか？ (curl コマンドはwebサーバが動いている自分自身に対して、だったりしませんか？)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ご教示してくださった点について確認したいと思います。

Comment: 「curl コマンドの実行」と「ブラウザでのアクセス」は同じ端末です。「curl コマンドの実行」もEC2上で実行していました（すみません、これだと確認したいことができていませんでした。）また、再度ローカル環境で「curl コマンドの実行」を行ったところEC2上と同様の結果になりました。

Comment: @user39764 そのあたりを整理して質問文を [edit] してみてくださいませんでしょうか？

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。いま編集しました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

解決いたしました。

■原因１
Nginx設定ファイルの格納パスを間違えていた。
■解決方法
rootパスから`/etc/nginx/conf.d/`直下に格納したら解決しました。

■原因２
・httpsで検索していたため
`http://IPアドレス/`で検索を行なっていたのですが、検索フォームで自動的に`https://IPアドレス/`となっていたためうまくいっていなかったみたいです。
■解決方法
Google Clomeの閲覧履歴データの削除からキャッシュされた画像のデータを削除したら解決しました。

ご回答・ご確認してくださった方々、ありがとうございました。